# Slider with transparency

Tags: css, html, slider, transparency

I have a problem with coding of sliders with transparency. I don't know how to start? Has anyone seen similar examples?

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean with transparency? imagine you read your question without any background knowledge.. how should someone give a specific answer to such a broad question.

Comment: ^ I think we need a better described question.

Answer (score 0):

With use the css:

```
.name_slider {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

the last value (0.2) is the opacity : 1 is black, 0 is transparent. Just try diferent value to find the desired opacity.